# Papervision3D Coordinate Axes

Tags: flash, papervision3d, axes, coordinate

I have a flash application and I use papervision3d library. I put my objects to the scene, no problem but I also want to show the coordinate axes (x,y and z) to user. 
Is there any way to show these axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the [UCS](http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/docs/org/papervision3d/objects/special/UCS.html) object:

```
scene.addChild(new UCS());
```

[Here](http://wonderfl.net/c/nggv)'s a very basic example:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import org.papervision3d.view.*;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.*;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.primitives.*;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.special.*;

    public class HelloPV3D extends Sprite {

        private var view:BasicView;

        public function HelloPV3D()  {
            view = addChild(new BasicView()) as BasicView;
            view.scene.addChild(new UCS());
            view.scene.addChild(new Sphere());
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
        }
        private function update(e:Event):void{
            view.camera.orbit(mouseY/stage.stageHeight,mouseX/stage.stageWidth,false);
            view.singleRender();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: UCS Demo]

Comment: +1 ha! Never knew about that. I rolled my own class that did about the same thing... Too bad papervision hasn't been resurrected. I always preferred it to away3d.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is. I wrote a class called **Trident3D** that represents the coordinate axes. Click [here](http://www.doublebow.net/articles/actionscript-3-0/trident-in-papervision3d) to see article about it or download the [demo](http://www.doublebow.net/uploads/assets/a006/trident_3d_demo.zip) that contains the source code.